# Javascipt swiper warnings fix

Tags: javascript, web, syntax, gulp, swiper.js

I'm making a site that uses the swiper slider.

src/js/app.js

```
import * as flsFunctions from "./modules/functions.js";
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import {
    Navigation,
    EffectFade,
    Pagination,
    Thumbs,
    Controller,
    FreeMode,
    Scrollbar,
    A11y,
    Mousewheel
} from 'swiper';
import AOS from 'aos';

flsFunctions.isWebp();

const swiper = new Swiper('.auctions-slider', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next1',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev1'
    },
    modules: [Navigation, EffectFade, Pagination],
    autoHeight: true,
    speed: 500, 
    slidesPerView: 2.8,
})
```

When saving a project, gulp gives the following messages

[Swiper warning screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J5C9.png)

[Swiper warning screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4otp0.png)

How to fix warnings

```
WARNING in ./src/js/app.js 24:11-21
"export 'Navigation' was not found in 'swiper'
```

I am using swiper version 5.2.1

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nft-landing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --build",
    "svgSprive": "gulp svgSprive",
    "zip": "gulp deployZIP --build",
    "deploy": "gulp deployFTP --build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-fonter": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-ttf2woff2": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-version-number": "^0.2.4",
    "gulp-webp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-webp-html-nosvg": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-webpcss": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-zip": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.0",
    "swiper": "^5.2.1",
    "vinyl-ftp": "^0.6.1",
    "webp-converter": "^2.2.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

I tried to find help on swiper syntax - [swiper 5.2.1](https://www.google.ru/search?q=swiper%205.2.1&newwindow=1&sxsrf=APwXEdeluP9glYpDaK1Tfk9h3oFZ1Bmn6Q%3A1687435066273&source=hp&ei=OjeUZILqDcXx6APCh4xw&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZJRFSt5CJuIJ9tPWUGIz7QayYPS8uk3t&oq=swiper&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIHCCMQigUQJzINCC4QgAQQFBCHAhCxAzINCAAQgAQQFBCHAhCxAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BAgjECc6CAgAEIAEELEDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QM6CAguEIAEELEDOhQILhCABBDHARCvARCYBRCeBRCZBToFCC4QgAQ6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBUABYmApg_hZoAHAAeACAAY4BiAGUBZIBAzMuM5gBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz), but I did not find anything suitable

I hope someone can help me with the swiper syntax.

content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentcontent content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content

I've tried

```
import * as flsFunctions from "./modules/functions.js";
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import {
    Navigation,
    EffectFade,
    Pagination,
    Thumbs,
    Controller,
    FreeMode,
    Scrollbar,
    A11y,
    Mousewheel
} from 'swiper/bundle';
import AOS from 'aos';

flsFunctions.isWebp();

const swiper = new Swiper('.auctions-slider', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next1',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev1'
    },
    modules: [Navigation, EffectFade, Pagination],
    autoHeight: true,
    speed: 500, 
    slidesPerView: 3,
})
```

and got this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yzFs.png)

The answer below did not help resolve the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
import {
Navigation,
EffectFade,
Pagination,
Thumbs,
Controller,
FreeMode,
Scrollbar,
A11y,
Mousewheel } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
```

Comment: don't replace element, you have replace the ... with required modules

Comment: Sorry for my english. Did you understand me?

Comment: package path - `swiper/element/bundle`. What should be specified instead of the element in line `swiper/element/bundle`? or enough `swiper/bundle` instead `swiper/element/bundle`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).